# Thousand separator in numeric input with jQuery and regularexpressions

Tags: jquery, regex, number-formatting

I need to make my numeric input in such mode: {1-3 numbers} {white-space} {3 numbers} {white-space} {3 numbers} {white-space} .. and so on..

For example, when user enters 1000 it should be converted to 1 000, than he enters 1 0000, and it will be converted to 10 000; on deleting last zero input value should return to 1 000

there's a **jquery plugin autonumeric**, but i need only this thousand separating function

my code looks like:

```
$('#myinput').live('keypress', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length == 3){
        newval = $(this).val().replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{2}$)/, '$1 $2');
    }
    if ($(this).val().length == 4){
        newval = $(this).val().replace(/([0-9])([0-9]{3}$)/, '$1 $2');
    }
    ...
    $(this).val(newval);
});
```

it doesn't work properly, as well as this:

```
newval  = $(this).val().replace(/(\S{1,3})([$0-9]{2})/g, '$1 $2');
newval2 = newval.replace(/([0-9]{1})[\s]([0-9]{1})[\s]/g, '$1$2 ');
```

this one fails on deleting last number

Comment: You could use the function given here: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html and replace the comma with a space in the while loop.

Comment: this function still doesn't work for me:

     function addCommas(nStr)
 {
  nStr += '';
  x = nStr.split('.');
  x1 = x[0];
  x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
  var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (rgx.test(x1)) {
   x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
  }
  return x1 + x2;
 }


$('#myinput').live('keypress', function(){
 
 newval = addCommas($(this).val());
  
 
 $(this).val(newval);
  
 });


it returns 1,0,0,0,000 for example

Answer (score 5):

EDIT:

A working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mxq3J/)

Example with monkey patch for cursor replacement: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mxq3J/1/)

---

From the code of [SugarJS](http://sugarjs.com)

```
/***
 * @method format([comma] = ',', [period] = '.')
 * @returns String
 * @short Formats the number to a readable string.
 * @extra [comma] is the character used for the thousands separator. [period] is the character used for the decimal point.
 * @example
 *
 *   (56782).format()           -> '56,782'
 *   (4388.43).format()         -> '4,388.43'
 *   (4388.43).format(' ')      -> '4 388.43'
 *   (4388.43).format('.', ',') -> '4.388,43'
 *
 ***/
'format': function(comma, period) {
  comma = comma || ',';
  period = period || '.';
  var split = this.toString().split('.');
  var numeric = split[0];
  var decimal = split.length > 1 ? period + split[1] : '';
  var reg = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while (reg.test(numeric)) {
    numeric = numeric.replace(reg, '$1' + comma + '$2');
  }
  return numeric + decimal;
}
```

Comment: How's that? It should work perfectly fine. What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @Ewout, will not work if you add/change anything anywhere except at the end of string @ "cursor replacement".

Comment: @Qtax: again, agreed, but it's better than nothing ;-) OP could maybe look into one of jQuery's mask plugins. Like http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/. These will produce the desired behaviour and leave your cursor where it is.

Comment: This code is not perfect: if I select the middle of the number and edit it the cursor jumps to the end of the input. (jquery autonumberic works well in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
var str = "1 2345 67 89  11";
str = str.replace(/\D+/g, '');
str = str.replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$& ');
```

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/4Wsqq/

This simple solution will not work with negative numbers nor decimals.

**Note** that there are problems with doing such things on a keypress/keydown/keyup event. My major annoyance would be that the cursor position will be moved to the end, which means that users can't really enter/change the value anywhere else but at the end of the string.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work properly, but thanks for the help :)
http://livemedical.net/exp.html

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? It's formatting the numbers just fine for me.

Comment: i press one - zero - zero - zero {HERE SHOUL BE SPACE 1 000} +zero => {10 000}, 'backspace' => {1 000}

have uploaded your code here: http://livemedical.net/exp.html

Comment: Backspace doesn't trigger the function. Use proper event that you want to listen on. You can see that it's working by again entering a number after hitting backspace couple of times, and it will reformat.

Comment: hm.. why? backspace is a key, and it has it's code in jQuery (event.which = 8) http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: @drdarwin, see example at http://jsfiddle.net/4Wsqq/ Also check the comments in your link, I quote: "If you want to use arrows, delete, backspace keys in Chrome you must use keydown. keypress on these keys work only in Firefox and Opera"

Comment: Aah. ;) got it, I'm using opera

Comment: @Qtax: actually you should use keyup. Keydown will render incorrect results.

Comment: @Ewout, works in Chrome for me with keydown, but I don't think you should use any of those, unless you can reposition the cursor correctly.

Comment: oh, my keyup, you're miracle 8)
Ewout Kleinsmann & Ewout are really code guru *)

Comment: @Qtax: Agreed. I added a little monkey patch to my example to fix most problems regarding this issue. drdarwin: you should use that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

add number-separator class to your input text element and add blow code to script

```
<input type="text" class="number-separator" placeholder="Enter Your Number Here...">





jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(document).on('input', '.number-separator', function (e) {
if (/^[0-9.,]+$/.test($(this).val())) {
  $(this).val(
    parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g, '')).toLocaleString('en')
  );
} else {
  $(this).val(
    $(this)
      .val()
      .substring(0, $(this).val().length - 1)
  );
}});});
```

You can see sample on:
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/number-thousand-separator/